# How to multiply polynomials in $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^n+1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, math-software

Consider the ring

$$R_q=\mathbb Z_q[X]/(X^n + 1),$$

where $q\equiv 1 \bmod 2n$ and $n$ is a power of $2$.

This is the quotient ring where the cosets are represented by polynomials up to $n-1$ in order.

I'd like to compute $c = a · b \bmod (X^n + 1)$, where $a$ and $b$ are polynomials in this ring, using Wolfram Cloud, or Wolfram Alpha, or anything easy to use.

This is for comparing with some code that I'm writing, that does this using NTT (Fast Fourier Transform for rings).

Is it possible?

For example:

$$(1x^0 + 2x^1 + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + 5x^4 + 6x^5 + 7x^6 + 8x^7)*(2x^0 + 5x^1 + 8x^2 + 11x^3 + 14x^4 + 17x^5 + 20x^6 + 23x^7) \mbox{ mod ($x^8+1$)} = ?$$

(where q = large, here, so all the coefficients fit)

Comment: Is this a one-off for checking the results from your code, and not a process you want to perform many times?

Comment: The ring in your title is a quotient of $\Bbb Z[x]$. In the text you use $\Bbb F_q[x]$.

Comment: WA: `PolynomialMod[(1x^0+2x^1+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+6x^5+7x^6+8x^7) * (2x^0+5x^1+8x^2+11x^3+14x^4+17x^5+20x^6+23x^7) , x^8+1]`.

Comment: @EricTowers this does not respect the $\mathbb{Z}_q$ though, am I rigth?

Comment: @Paprika : With $q = 11$: `PolynomialMod[(1x^0+2x^1+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+6x^5+7x^6+8x^7) * (2x^0+5x^1+8x^2+11x^3+14x^4+17x^5+20x^6+23x^7) , x^8+1, Modulus -> 11]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you want in the Wolfram language is PolynomialMod. See documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialMod.html).   PolynomialMod[(1x^0+2x^1+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+6x^5+7x^6+8x^7) * (2x^0+5x^1+8x^2+11x^3+14x^4+17x^5+20x^6+23x^7) , {x^8+1,2}]
will return `x^2 + x^4 + x^5` after reducing first mod $x^8+1$, and then reducing coefficients mod $2$.

Comment: this does not respect the $\mathbb{Z}_q$ though, am I rigth? The product could 'overflow' and not be reduced mod $\mathbb{Z}_q$

Comment: Replace the {x^8+1,2} with {x^8+1,q} and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

The result is
$$
2(162x^7 + 20x^6 - 87x^5 - 162x^4 - 208x^3 - 228x^2 - 225x -
 202).
$$
One can simply introduce the relation $x^8:=-1$ and then do the  multiplication.